# xdrlib.Error: value=-915689825 not in enum ClaimableBalanceIDType, when I try to claim the created balance

Tags: stellar-sdk, xdr, python-sdk

so I'm trying to implement [claimable_balances](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/blob/master/examples/claimable_balances.py) example using the python-sdk, I'm able to use `append_create_claimable_balance_op` and create a claimable balance from the sponsor's account.

but I don't know what the `balance_id` that is required for claiming the balance back for the claimant.

I tried using the `id` from [`create_claimable_balance_resp`](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/blob/master/examples/claimable_balances.py#L29) dictionary as `balance_id`, but that's when I started seeing this weird error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "claimable_balance.py", line 45, in <module>
    claim_claimable_balance_te.sign(claimant_keypair)
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/base_transaction_envelope.py", line 55, in sign
    tx_hash = self.hash()
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/base_transaction_envelope.py", line 33, in hash
    return sha256(self.signature_base())
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/transaction_envelope.py", line 57, in signature_base
    tx_packer.pack_Transaction(tx.to_xdr_object())
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/transaction.py", line 101, in to_xdr_object
    operations = [operation.to_xdr_object() for operation in self.operations]
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/transaction.py", line 101, in <listcomp>
    operations = [operation.to_xdr_object() for operation in self.operations]
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/operation/operation.py", line 133, in to_xdr_object
    return Xdr.types.Operation(source_account, self._to_operation_body())
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/operation/claim_claimable_balance.py", line 37, in _to_operation_body
    balance_id = ClaimableBalanceID.from_xdr(base64.b64encode(balance_id_bytes))
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/xdr/StellarXDR_type.py", line 1904, in from_xdr
    return xdr_unpacked.unpack_ClaimableBalanceID()
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/xdr/StellarXDR_pack.py", line 3806, in unpack_ClaimableBalanceID
    data.type = self.unpack_ClaimableBalanceIDType()
  File "/home/greyhound/miniconda3/envs/gg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stellar_sdk/xdr/StellarXDR_pack.py", line 3799, in unpack_ClaimableBalanceIDType
    raise XDRError('value=%s not in enum ClaimableBalanceIDType' % data)
xdrlib.Error: value=-915689825 not in enum ClaimableBalanceIDType
```

but in laboratory I'm able to see a `claimableBalanceIdTypeV0` as `iHe9OulZl9/eo+Z7tMZe+nHX3gSL6XhjR96qrUP7uHk=` from TransactionResult XDR type which doesn't resemble anything like the [`balance_id` shown in the github example](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/blob/master/examples/claimable_balances.py#L33). I tried using that too, it started throwing `Invalid hex string`  or along those lines.

tl;dr.
Please tell me what `balance_id` is and where I can find it to claim my balance back.

Environment:
I'm testing it out in the horizon testnet only. The [entire output and error is here as well.](https://pastebin.com/qvfL7F0k).
python version: `3.7.9`, stellar:

```python
>>> import stellar_sdk
>>> stellar_sdk.__version__
'2.8.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
def get_balance_id(create_claimable_balance_resp):

    effects_link = create_claimable_balance_resp["_links"]["effects"]["href"].split("{")[0]
    resp = requests.get(effects_link)
    content = json.loads(resp.content)
    balance_id = content["_embedded"]["records"][0]["balance_id"]
    return balance_id
```

worked for me. where `create_claimable_balance_resp` is the response given by the result of `TransactionBuilder` with `append_create_claimable_balance_op`, like this [here](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/blob/master/examples/claimable_balances.py#L29).

[In their docs](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/claimable-balance/#example) it says

> Either party could also check the `/effects` of the transaction, query `/claimable_balances` with different filters, etc. Note that while (1) may be unavailable in some SDKs as its just a helper,

Note: IDK how it will work for multiple claimants yet.